# Why does SetConsoleInfo window give incorrect parameter error?

Tags: python, windows, console, pywin32

I am trying to make a console program using the pywin32 module

My code is:

```py
import win32con, win32console, time, random

MyCon = win32console.CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(DesiredAccess = win32con.GENERIC_READ | win32con.GENERIC_WRITE, ShareMode = 0, SecurityAttributes = None, Flags = 1)
MyCon.SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer()
rect = win32console.PySMALL_RECTType(20, 30, 600, 600)
MyCon.SetConsoleWindowInfo(Absolute = False, ConsoleWindow = rect)

while True:
    y = str(random.randint(1,100)) + ' '
    MyCon.WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(Characters = y, WriteCoord = win32console.PyCOORDType(5,6))
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

This is the error i am facing when i am trying to run the program from cmd.exe
[image: The error]

I am giving the parameters as said in the docs here http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyConsoleScreenBuffer__SetConsoleWindowInfo_meth.html

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [[MS.Docs]: SetConsoleWindowInfo function - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo#remarks) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> ***The function fails if the specified window rectangle extends beyond the boundaries of the console screen buffer***. This means that the **Top** and **Left** members of the *lpConsoleWindow* rectangle (or the calculated top and left coordinates, if *bAbsolute* is FALSE) cannot be less than zero. Similarly, the **Bottom** and **Right** members (or the calculated bottom and right coordinates) cannot be greater than (screen buffer height – 1) and (screen buffer width – 1), respectively. The function also fails if the **Right** member (or calculated right coordinate) is less than or equal to the **Left** member (or calculated left coordinate) or if the **Bottom** member (or calculated bottom coordinate) is less than or equal to the **Top** member (or calculated top coordinate).

Your argument combination (relative coordinates + given rectangle) must have gone beyond screen buffer boundaries.
Below is an example that works.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import msvcrt
import random
import sys
import time

import win32api as wapi
import win32con as wcon
import win32console as wcons


def main(*argv):
    buf = wcons.CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(DesiredAccess=wcon.GENERIC_READ | wcon.GENERIC_WRITE, ShareMode=0, SecurityAttributes=None, Flags=wcons.CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER)
    buf.SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer()
    #print("csbi: {:}\nlcws: {:}".format(buf.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(), buf.GetLargestConsoleWindowSize()))

    so_buf = wcons.GetStdHandle(wcons.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    so_csbi = so_buf.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()
    #print("csbi: {:}\nlcws: {:}".format(so_csbi, so_buf.GetLargestConsoleWindowSize()))
    #rect = wcons.PySMALL_RECTType(0, 1, 0, 1)
    buf.SetConsoleWindowInfo(Absolute=True, ConsoleWindow=so_csbi["Window"])
    write_coord = wcons.PyCOORDType(10, 4)
    buf = so_buf  # @TODO - cfati: Uncomment this line to write on the same output buffer (and thus preserve screen contents)
    while not msvcrt.kbhit():
        chrs = "------- {:d} -------".format(random.randint(1, 100))
        buf.WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(Characters=chrs, WriteCoord=write_coord)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    wapi.CloseHandle(buf)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output** (last value after pressing a key):

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073678914]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
>           ------- 63 -------
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, can you please tell me how to find the max buffer height and width and it's current coordinates so i can create a command to check it for running it on any machine ?

Comment: You're welcome! Uncomment `#print("csbi: {:}\nlcws: {:}".format(so_csbi, so_buf.GetLargestConsoleWindowSize()))`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, will finally be able to make a command prompt snake game that doesn't blink since it scrolls down and flex in school :)

Comment: There's *URL* with an example (*C*) at the end of the one in the answer.